# Disable UAC on apps that installed from network drive

Tags: powershell, uac

So I need to uninstall some program and clean all the leftovers (folders + registry)
and then install the new app with all it dependencies - all this on 150 workstation

I've created a Powershell script and it's doing all the mention above without any issues,
the issue begins when I need to run the installation, it's located on a network share, here is the syntax:

```
Set-Location "\\imapps\FileSiteClientInstall\Setup Imanage\DRIVE -iManage Drive for Windows 10.2.6.48" 
Start-Process iManageDrive.exe /s
```

The issue is that i have 6 lines like this one (each installation file is in a different folder),
and when I run this from the network I'am getting this UAC
is there a way to disable it, and make my script to run fully automatically?

[image: UAC]

Thanks alot for your help :)

Comment: This is not a UAC prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, not really UAC for what most people think of UAC. This is warning about running an executable from an untrusted location (not on a local drive). You'd get the same thing with a script that you download from the internet. What you can do is use the `Unblock-File` cmdlet to get past that warning like this:

```
Set-Location "\\imapps\FileSiteClientInstall\Setup Imanage\DRIVE -iManage Drive for Windows 10.2.6.48" 
Unblock-File .\iManageDrive.exe
Start-Process iManageDrive.exe /s
```

This should mark the file as safe, and avoid the prompt you've been getting.

Comment: Thanks, I will test it tomorrow and update, thanks alot for your help